# Extracting images from a text file of 100 image urls using java

Tags: java, file, url, file-io

I have a text file containing lots of image urls line by line. I need to get a Java code for automatically extracting those images and saving those images into a file. I know how to save the image from a single URL, but how could I modify the code to do multi threading? I want to get all the images under a single folder with its original file name. I tried to google out many codes, but everything was a failure. Please help me to find a solution. Answers will be highly appreciated.

The code I used to save a single image is:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;

public class SaveImageFromUrl {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String imageUrl = "http://http://img.emol.com/2015/04/25/nepalterremoto02ok_2260.jpg";
        String destinationFile = "/home/abc/image.jpg";
        saveImage(imageUrl, destinationFile);
    }

    public static void saveImage(String imageUrl, String destinationFile) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
        InputStream is = url.openStream();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile);

        byte[] b = new byte[2048];
        int length;

        while ((length = is.read(b)) != -1) {
            os.write(b, 0, length);
        }
        is.close();
        os.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: `ImageIO.read` and `ImageIO.write` ([Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) and [Writing/Saving an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/saveimage.html)). Use some kind of `ExecutorService`, probably a fixed pool service, load all the entries from the text file, add a "task" to the `ExecutorService` for each entry.  Run until it's all done (maybe using something like `invokeAll`)

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of pre-existing APIs...

- Use `Files.readAllLines` to read the file
- `ImageIO.read` and `ImageIO.write` to download the file
- The `Executor` API to run concurrent tasks to help make it quicker

So, basically, downloading the image from each URL is the same process, which can encapsulated into a simple task.

```
public class DownloadImageFromURLTask implements Callable<File> {

    private URL url;
    private String path;

    public DownloadImageFromURLTask(URL url, String path) {
        this.url = url;
        this.path = path;
    }

    @Override
    public File call() throws Exception {

        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(url);
        String name = url.getPath();
        name = name.substring(name.lastIndexOf("/"));
        File output = new File(path, name);
        ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", output);

        return output;
    }

}
```

I've used `Callable` here, because it will plugin into the `Executor` API and allow me to get the return result, which is the `File` where the image was downloaded.

So next, we need to read the URLs from the text file and build a list of tasks to executed...

```
        List<String> listOfURLs = Files.readAllLines(new File("ListOfURLs.txt").toPath());
        List<DownloadImageFromURLTask> listOfTasks = new ArrayList<>(listOfURLs.size());
        String path = "/home/abc";
        for (String url : listOfURLs) {
            listOfTasks.add(new DownloadImageFromURLTask(new URL(url), path));
        }
```

For simplicity, I've just used `Files.readAllLines`

Next, we need to execute all the tasks...

```
        ExecutorService exector = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
        List<Future<File>> listOfFutures = exector.invokeAll(listOfTasks);
```

This is uses a fixed sized thread pool, this allows for some performance adjusting on our part, as each task will be pooled until a thread becomes available to run it.

The use of `invokeAll` here is a blocking call, meaning that until all the tasks have either completed or failed, it won't return.  Convenient.

Optionally, you can process the resulting `List` of `Future`'s, these carry the return results of the `Callable`s

```
        for (int index = 0; index < listOfFutures.size(); index++) {
            Future<File> future = listOfFutures.get(index);
            try {
                File file = future.get();
            } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
                String url = listOfURLs.get(index);
                System.out.println("Failed to download image from " + url);
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

In this example, it's processing the list looking for failed tasks.

Have a look at [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html), [Writing/Saving an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/saveimage.html), [Executors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html) and [Reading, Writing, and Creating Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

You can use [curl](http://osxdaily.com/2014/02/13/download-with-curl/) on the command line to fetch multiple files. However, I assume you are trying to learn Java concurrency, so I redid your program using concurrency:

**Update: This now processes the file and downloads each URL and keeps the original filename**

```
/**
 * Created by justin on 6/20/15.
 */

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.lang.System;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Files;

class ImageSaver implements Runnable {

    private final String imageUrl;
    private final String destinationFile;
    private Exception exception;

    public ImageSaver(String imageUrl, String destinationFile) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
        this.destinationFile = destinationFile;
        this.exception = null;
    }

    public boolean isFail() {
        return exception != null;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.imageUrl + " -> " + this.destinationFile + " Error: " + exception.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            URL url = null;
            url = new URL(imageUrl);
            System.out.println("Getting " + imageUrl);
            url.openConnection();
            InputStream is = url.openStream();
            System.out.println("Opening " + imageUrl);
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile);

            byte[] b = new byte[2048];
            int length;

            while ((length = is.read(b)) != -1) {
                os.write(b, 0, length);
            }

            is.close();
            os.close();
            System.out.println("Finished getting " + imageUrl);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            exception = e;
        }

    }

}


public class SaveImageFromUrl {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length < 2) {
            System.out.println("Usage: <file with urls on each line> <dest path>");
            return;
        }
        String destPath = args[1];
        List<String> listOfURLs = Files.readAllLines(new File(args[0]).toPath());
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        List<ImageSaver> save = new ArrayList<ImageSaver>();

        for (String path : listOfURLs) {

            String fn = new File(path).getName();
            ImageSaver worker = new ImageSaver(path, destPath + fn);
            save.add(worker);
            executor.execute(worker);
        }
        executor.shutdown();
        while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
            Thread.yield();
        }
        for (ImageSaver s : save) {
            if (s.isFail()) {
                System.out.println("Failed to download " + s);
            }
        }
        executor.shutdown();
        System.out.println("All Done");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion , i tried Wget -i <file.csv> -o log.txt to extract the images from the text files of url . but it is too slow and i actually wanted to learn Java multi threading.

Comment: sorry for not mentioning that the text file is inside my local folder and it contains  100 image-links. i need to get all the images from that file. the code above cannot open an text file.

Comment: I updated my solution so it does what you asked for now.  The first argument is a file with urls.  The second argument is a directory you want to copy things into.

Answer (score 0):

To get image from url text you can use below code:

```
public class SaveImageFromUrl {
    BufferedImage img = null;

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        String path = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1e/Stonehenge.jpg";
        String destinationFile = "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop";

        try {
            BufferedImage tmp = ImageIO.read(new URL(path));
            ImageIO.write(tmp, "jpg", new File(destinationFile + "\\" + "image" + ".jpg"));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception ex  ///" + ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you scale the images?

Comment: Thanks Mr  "saka1029"