# setRGB not working in Runnable Mandelbrot set

Tags: java, parallel-processing, runnable, mandelbrot

I need to draw the Mandelbrot set using parallel programming, the language used is Java. I employ Runnable tasks to do that. As setRGB is synchronized, I don't need locks to control concurrency and also the BufferedImage shared between all threads is accessed in parallel so it should not be a problem of concurrency. Here is the code below:

```
public class MandelParalelo extends JFrame 
implements Runnable{
 private final int MAX_ITER = 100000;
 private final double ZOOM = 150;
 private static BufferedImage Imagen;
 private double zx, zy, cX, cY, tmp;
 private int nTareas = 6;
 private int linf, lsup;

 public void run()
 {
    for (int y = linf; y < lsup; y++) {
       for (int x = 0; x < getWidth(); x++) {
         zx = zy = 0;
         cX = (x - 400) / ZOOM;
         cY = (y - 300) / ZOOM;
         int iter = MAX_ITER;
         while (zx * zx + zy * zy < 4 && iter > 0) {
                 tmp = zx * zx - zy * zy + cX;
                 zy = 2.0 * zx * zy + cY;
                 zx = tmp;
                 iter--;
         }
         Imagen.setRGB(x, y, iter | (iter << 8));//setRGB es synchronized
   }
  }
 }
public MandelParalelo(int i, int s)
{
  linf = i;
  lsup = s;
}

public MandelParalelo() {
  super("Conjunto de Mandelbrot");
  setBounds(100, 100, 800, 600);
  setResizable(false);
  setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  Imagen = new BufferedImage(getWidth(), getHeight(),
      BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
  ExecutorService ejecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);
  int inf = 0, tVentana = getHeight()/nTareas, sup = tVentana;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < nTareas; i++)
    {  
        ejecutor.execute(new MandelParalelo(inf, sup));
        inf = sup;
        sup += tVentana; 
    }
    
    ejecutor.shutdown();
    
    while(!ejecutor.isTerminated()){}
  

}
public void paint(Graphics g) {
  g.drawImage(Imagen, 0, 0, this);
 }
public static void main(String[] args) {
  new MandelParalelo().setVisible(true);     
 }
}
```

What I have been returned is a black Image:
[image]

Comment: For one, read [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

Comment: First get it working with a single Thread.

Comment: @camickr Yeah in single thread works

Comment: Replace your while loop with ejecutor.[awaitTermination](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination(long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)).  Although, I think awaiting termination undermines your attempt at parallelism…

Comment: Guess I don't understand the concept of parallel programming. I changed the thread pool from 8 to 1 and it still didn't work. I have only used an ExecutorService to use multiple processors to handle discreet tasks. For example https://stackoverflow.com/a/67348202/131872 shows how to load thumbnail images. I wasn't aware you could solve a mandelbrot in eight pieces and put it back together into one.